# Show that $\int_0^1x^4f_\theta(x)dx$ is strictly decreasing

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Define, for $\theta>0$, $$f_\theta(x)=\bigg(1+\dfrac{\theta}{1-x} \bigg) \cdot \exp{\bigg(-\dfrac{\theta x}{1-x}\bigg)}$$ with $x\in[0,1)$. Show that $$g(\theta):=\int_0^1x^4f_\theta(x)dx$$ is a strictly decreasing function of $\theta$.

After some algebra, I get $$g(\theta)=\theta \bigg[\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^4e^{-x}}{(\theta+x)^5}dx+\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^4e^{-x}}{(\theta+x)^6}dx \bigg]$$ After this, I am stuck. In fact the expression seems too frightening to even do integration by parts. I suppose by parts will not be of much help here because there will be no direct cancellation. But who am I to know!

Anyway, I would love some help with this. Any usable hint(preferably not an answer) will be appreciated. Also, is there any method in which such huge functions can be worked out?

Comment: Hint: Try to show that $g'(\theta) < 0$. Since $x^4 f_\theta(x)$ is $C^1$, you have: $$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\theta}\int_0^1 x^4f_\theta(x)\,{\rm d}x = \int_0^1 \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\theta} (x^4f_\theta(x)) \,{\rm d}x.$$
I'm leaving this as a comment because I'm not sure that it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Integration by parts leads to:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}g_\theta=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^4}{(1+z)^6}\left(1+\theta(z+1)\right)e^{-\theta z}\,dz &=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^4 e^{-\theta z}}{(1+z)^6}\,dz+\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^4 \theta e^{-\theta z}}{(1+z)^5}\,dz\\&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{4z^3 e^{-\theta z}}{(1+z)^6}\,dz\end{eqnarray*}$$
and now it is quite trivial that $g_\theta$ is decreasing.